# If Enter key hit - show message. Else - type as normal

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keyboard-events

If the user hits the enter key, I want to show a message saying the enter key was hit. Else, I want to type in the textbox as normal.

```
private void enterCheck(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)    
        {
               MessageBox.Show("Enter Was Clicked");
        }
    }
```

If enter is hit the message is displayed correctly. However, if I try to type a sentence, nothing appears in the textbox.

This will work...

```
private void enterCheck(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)    
        {
               MessageBox.Show("Enter Was Clicked");
        }   
        else
        {
               MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
        }
    }
```

However I don't want a messagebox showing every letter that was typed.

Comment: Just get rid of the whole `else` block.

Comment: @itsme86 I tried doing that and the same thing happens

Comment: What event is `enterCheck` tied to?

Comment: Also, why are you having to check the active control? The control that sent it will be in the `sender` parameter. And as long as you only subscribed controls that you want to do an enter check on to this method, then only those controls will trigger this.

Comment: I have a textBox with your function linked to the KeyDown event. If i press enter, the message box is shown. If i press anything else, text appears in the textbox. This works fine for me.

Comment: @itsme86 I changed that thank you. However it still does not work

Comment: Are you sure you're subscribed to the textbox1.KeyDown event? It's not some other control's event?

Comment: @itsme86 It was mentioned that the MessageBox did show up, so this would have to be the case

Comment: @Michael Is the textbox linked to another event? Are there other events than the KeyDown? Something that could prevent the text from being entered? Like TextChanged?

Comment: @itsme86 I checked and it is the correct control (textbox1)

Comment: @MasterXD No that is the only event

Comment: Does the `textbox1.ReadOnly` property equal false? I am running out of suggestions here...

Comment: @MasterXD Yup readonly is false

Comment: Can you try creating a new textbox with the same event and the same code to see if it will work there? Just make it a seperate function like textBox2_KeyDown

Comment: @MasterXD Ok give me a sec. In the meantime I updated the question. Take a look please. Very interesting and odd that a messagebox works

Comment: Just so you know, the second code field is exactly the same as the first...

Comment: @MasterXD The same thing occurs with a new textbox

Comment: Did you make the textBox2 fire KeyDown in its own function? textBox2_KeyDown and not enterCheck? Btw, the two codes you've entered are identical and the messageBox should only show when enter is pressed, not all other buttonseither way.

Comment: @SimonKlaver Whoops! I corrected that thank you

Comment: What do you mean "The other code works"? What are the results (what happens exactly)? And what do you mean "I don't want a messagebox showing every letter that was typed"? Your code will NOT show a message box UNLESS you press Enter. How come does it appear when every other button is pressed?

Comment: @MasterXD Sorry I was rushing that is what i meant. If i put a messagebox in the else statement, the text will appear in the textbox. If i take out the else block, the text does NOT appear when i type

Comment: Try, inside the else statement, to add `e.Handled = true;` instead of the current messagebox

Comment: @MasterXD The else statement is in the event. Also e.handled = true did NOT work. the only thing that works is the message box. That makes absolutely 0 sense.

Comment: Try `(sender as TextBox).Refresh()`!

Comment: Did you properly clean and rebuild between all tries?

Comment: @MasterXD Ok I cleaned it up and retried e.handled = true and it worked! Thank you so much! Thank you Simon Klaver also!

Comment: @MasterXD Repost your answer and I will mark as correct

Comment: Could you accept my answer then? Please :D Oh... thanks! That was some hassel!

Comment: @MasterXD You definitely earned the accept answer. Thank you once again

Comment: No prob. Have a nice day :D Happy programming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void enterCheck(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Please work! This is the most confusing I've ever encountered!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `KeyPress` event:

```
// This event occurs after the KeyDown event and can be used to prevent
// characters from entering the control.
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Was Pressed");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying KeyPressEventArgs does not contain a definition for KeyCode